# Using a repeat control to display more than one scoped variable created by a search query

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a button that does a search of a field in a database and puts the results of the field in a viewScope variable.
Then I use a repeat control to display the variable.  From what I was able to discern, I set the data source of the repeat control to the viewscope variable and use a computed field to access the variable by getting the value of the repeat control use the "rowIndex" property because the return is multiple values.
My question is:
Can I use this method to display more than one field in the record?  If so, how?
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button id="button1" value="Create a Search">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:searchFormula = '@Begins(Stu_LastName; "Se")';
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(searchFormula);

var docItems = [];
viewScope.Firstname = [];

var i = 0;
var doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
var tmpDoc:NotesDocument;
while (doc != null) {
    docItems = doc.getItems();
    if (doc.hasItem("stu_status")) {
        var status = [];
        status = doc.getItemValue("stu_status");
        if (status[0] == "1")
            if (doc.hasItem("Stu_Firstname")) {
                item = doc.getItemValue("Stu_Firstname");
                viewScope.Firstname.push(item);
                i++
        }
        tmpDoc = dc.getNextDocument(doc);
        doc.recycle();
        doc = tmpDoc;
        if (i > 50000) {
            print("possible loop - breaking now");
            break;
        }
    }
}
var text = "The length of Firstname is " + viewScope.Firstname.length;
print(text);}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true"
        id="pager1" for="repeat1">
    </xp:pager>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{viewScope.Firstname}"
        var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("repeat1").getValue()[rowIndex]}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: There's been many many shows on repeat control on my NotesIn9 screencast.  The blog is at notesin9.com and a list of shows is at XPages.TV.  I recommend you checking that out.  Even they very old shows would have repeat control examples.  That might help you.

Comment: I will look.  But I do understand how to use repeat controls and have looked at some of the your broadcasts.  I am just confused as to how to pass the results of a  datacollection created by a search button to a repeat control.  But I will definitely look at some more NotesIn9 screencasts.

Comment: Did you see my 3rd ever show?  "Intro to Searching"?   That used a viewPanel but a repeat control should be very similar.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxZw2eZzP5Y

Comment: I have a search that returns a NotesDocumentCollection.  In the example the NotesDocumentCollection contains all document where the lastname starts with "Se" and the status == 1. The code has changed a little because of other suggestions that I have received.   Each document has several fields that I want to display in the repeat control.  Your notesin9 video "repeating a repeat" indicates that this can be done (views and collections).  I have used a repeat control with a view as a data source.  But this collection is causing my troubles - perhaps because it is NotSerializable.

Comment: Which means I can't use a Scope variable to store the list of values.  *****var searchFormula = '@Begins(Stu_LastName; "Se") & @Contains(Stu_Status; "1")';
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(searchFormula);

viewScope.docItems = dc; ******** returns the "java.io.NotSerializableException: lotus.domino.local.DocumentCollection"
error.

Comment: I think I am getting closer.

Comment: You really can't put lotus.domino objects into scope because of the serializable issues. But you can create a SSJS function that returns a document collection.  You could call this function from your repeat control...

Comment: Got it.  Yes. The Scoped variable is the searchformula which is passed to create the datacollection in as the data source for the repeat control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are meaning you want to get more data than just the FirstName to try and build a table of that data? e.g. FirstName, LastName, Email etc.

If so, you would be better off building the search to return the data in the `NotesDocumentCollection` rather than getting the collection and pulling out data into a `viewScope` Array. e.g. `searchFormula = '@Begins(Stu_LastName; "Se") & @Contains(Stu_Status; "1")';`

Each `rowData` entry would be a document.  You could then refer to the fields as `#{rowData.FirstName}' or`#{rowData.LastName}' in computed fields within the repeat.

Comment: This sounds like what I want.  But I am missing a link here.  I create my NotesDocumentCollection with the Search Button.  It is assigned to the variable "dc".  How do I link that to the rowData in the Data Binding definition for the repeat?

Comment: I might just need to do some more experimentation.  I will get back to you on Monday.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need a Scoped variable array to hold the document ids.  However, the note document ids are not serializable and cannot be stored in a scoped variable.

Comment: I think I am getting closer.

Comment: Got it.  Yes. The Scoped variable is the searchformula which is passed to create the datacollection in as the data source for the repeat control. Thanks

Comment: Decided to submit an example in case anybody needs an example.   Downloaded data from a website and created a database with 3 fields:  State AirportName AirportCode.  The search searches for the state and returns the rest of the information.  Added code as an answer because comments do not allow the number of characters needed for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You made it too hard! Just use the rowData in your computed text field. That is the value of each item in the referenced value in the repeat (your viewScope variable). The index is the numeric index, starting at zero.

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{rowData}">

    </xp:text>
```

Comment: Interesting how when you add the string   value="#{rowData}"     directly to the source or by adding the string   rowData  to an advanced binding via expression language, the value property shows Simple data binding with a Data source of rowData with nothing in the Bind to dropdown.  However, rowData is not a choice for Simple data binding initially.  This does not really answer my question, however - because I still don't see how to present more than one value from the search as I just have the one viewScope variable for the repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to submit an example in case anybody needs an example. Downloaded data from a website and created a database with 3 fields: State AirportName AirportCode. The search searches for the state and returns the rest of the information. Added code as an answer because comments do not allow the number of characters needed for the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:panel style="margin-left:10.0px;background-color:rgb(204,230,255);padding-top:20.0px;padding-bottom:5.0px" id="Search3Panel">



        <xp:table>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td colspan="2">



                <xp:label value="This Panel Shows a Repeat Control Using a notesDataCollection as a datasource." id="label5" style="font-weight:bold"></xp:label></xp:td>

            </xp:tr>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:label id="label1" value="State"></xp:label></xp:td>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:inputText id="searchTerm"></xp:inputText></xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td></xp:td>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:button id="button1" value="Search">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler1">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var searchTerm:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("searchTerm").getValue();
viewScope.State = searchTerm;
viewScope.searchFormula = '@Begins(State; "'+ searchTerm + '")' 
sessionScope.panelSee = false;}]]></xp:this.action>

                            <xp:this.script>
                                <xp:executeClientScript>
                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var ret = true;
for(var i=0; i<document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){ 
    if(document.forms[0].elements[i].name == "#{id:searchTerm}" ){ 
        var choice = document.forms[0].elements[i].value;
        if (!choice) {
            alert("Please enter letters at the beginning of the state you want to search for.");
            return false
        }
    }
}]]></xp:this.script>
                                </xp:executeClientScript>
                            </xp:this.script>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>
                    <xp:button id="button4" value="Clear">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler2">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.State = "";
viewScope.searchFormula = "";
sessionScope.panelSee = true;}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
        </xp:table>
    </xp:panel><xp:panel style="margin-left:10.0px;background-color:rgb(204,230,255);padding-top:10.0px;padding-bottom:10.0px" id="Repeat3Panel">
        <xp:label id="label4" value="You are searching for States that begin with " style="font-weight:bold"><xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (!!viewScope.State) {
    return true;
} else { 
    return false;
}}]]></xp:this.rendered></xp:label><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField8" value="#{viewScope.State}" style="font-weight:bold"></xp:text>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:repeat id="repeat3" rows="30" var="APCodes">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(viewScope.searchFormula);
return dc}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField5" value="#{APCodes.State}">
            </xp:text>
            &#160;&#160;
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField6" value="#{APCodes.Airport}">
            </xp:text>
            &#160;&#160;
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField7" value="#{APCodes.Code}">
            </xp:text><xp:br></xp:br></xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel></xp:view>
```